# изменение пароля при первом входе на сайт

Tags: wordpress

Существует ли плагин на изменение пароля при первом входе, что бы пользователю после первого входа сразу предлагали сменить его пароль. Или каким образом можно это сделать ?

Comment: Юзеру нечего сбрасывать. По умолчанию пароль не высылается и даже не генерируется. После регистрации юзера ему высылается ссылка, перейдя по которой он задаёт себе пароль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такая штука:

https://github.com/lumpysimon/wp-force-password-change

> Этот плагин перенаправляет недавно зарегистрированных пользователей на
> страницу Admin -> Edit Profile при первом входе в систему. Пока они не
> изменят свой пароль, они не смогут получить доступ ни к интерфейсу, ни
> к другим страницам админ-панели. Также отображается уведомление,
> информирующее их о том, что они должны изменить свой пароль.
>
> Новые администраторы также должны изменить свой пароль, но в качестве
> меры безопасности они также могут получить доступ к странице Admin ->
> Plugins.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос еще один. Есть какой то код на безопасную смену пароля ? Например я создал свою страницу и перенаправляю пользователя на нее и там он уже меняет пароль

Comment: Если готовые решения - есть https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-reset-password/

Если кодом - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367374/force-user-to-change-their-password-on-the-frontend-at-the-first-login-and-passw

Comment: это немного не то. Нужна именно смена пароля после первой авторизации. Вот плагин который вы скинули правильно работает, но я отключил пользователям доступ к панели админа